# Make Loop JSON into columnar in List Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a JSON result that I want to render as column in list item

```
success: function (json) {
  for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
    $('#hasil').append("<div class='list-group-item'><div class='col-md-3' id='col1'></div><div class='col-md-3' id='col2'></div><div class='col-md-3' id='col3'></div></div>");
  }
}
```

But I'm lost in how to make the row to populate as a column.

The JSON result is:

```
image1
image2
image3
image4
image5
image6
```

I want to display it as

```
image1 image2 image3
image4 image5 image6
```

any hints?

Comment: My first "hint" would be, take a normal piece of HTML with how you want to display it as. Then play around with the pieces that make up the design, then write code to output it in the exact same fashion. Compare output with what you designed in html first, then, profit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increment `i` by `3`  and generate 3 elements within a single loop statement.

```js
var json = {
  data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
}

for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i += 3) {
  $('#hasil').append("<div class='list-group-item'><div class='col-md-3' id='col1'>" + json.data[i] + "</div><div class='col-md-3' id='col2'>" + json.data[i + 1] + "</div><div class='col-md-3' id='col3'>" + json.data[i + 2] + "</div></div>")
}
```

```css
.list-group-item div {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hasil"></div>
```

---

ALso, it's better to append the entire string after the for loop by generating HTML into a string variable.

```js
var json = {
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  },
  html = '';

for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i += 3) {
  html += "<div class='list-group-item'><div class='col-md-3' id='col1'>" + json.data[i] + "</div><div class='col-md-3' id='col2'>" + json.data[i + 1] + "</div><div class='col-md-3' id='col3'>" + json.data[i + 2] + "</div></div>";
}

$('#hasil').append(html);
```

```css
.list-group-item div {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hasil"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var json = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
$('.container').append(`<div class='row'></div>`);
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  $('.row').append(`
    <div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4' id='col${json[i]}'>Image${json[i]}</div>`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Bootstrap default column size in a row is 12 so you need to define the col size as 4 instead of 3.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data you want is json.data.X then you just need to include the json like so

```
var html = `<div class='list-group-item'>
    <div class='col-md-3' id='col1'>`+ json.data[0] +`</div>
    <div class='col-md-3' id='col2'>`+ json.data[1] +`</div>
    <div class='col-md-3' id='col3'>`+ json.data[2] +`</div>
</div>`;

$('#hasil').append(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Bootstrap Grid is based in 12 columns https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid you can make cols of "4" as width to get 3 per row.

```
success: function (json) {
     $('#hasil').append("<div class='list-group-item row'>");
     for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) 
     {
        $('#hasil').append("<div class='col-md-4' id='col"+i+"'>"+json.data[i]+"</div>");
     }
     $('#hasil').append("</div>");
```